# Dafny, Dutch Flag, loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop

Tags: z3, verification, dafny

in the program below I am creating something like Dutch national flag problem and following the same logic which is also provided [here](https://youtu.be/dQC5m-GZYbk) 
the program sorts array of 0s,1s and 2s in the manner all 1s in the beginning 0s in the middle and 2s at the end. `[1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2]`.
but at the loop invariants, I get the error `This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.`

initially, `i` and `j` are at index 0, and `k` at last index. the logic is that j moves up if it sees 2, swap with k and k reduces if sees 0 just `j` moves up, and if sees 1 swap with `i` and both `i` and `j` increase.

the code is also here in [rise4fun](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/SWHr)

```
        method sort(input: array?<int>)
        modifies input
        requires input !=null;
        requires input.Length>0;
        requires forall x::0<=x<input.Length ==> input[x]==0||input[x]==1||input[x]==2;
        ensures sorted(input);
        {
            var k: int := input.Length;
            var i, j: int := 0 , 0;
            while(j != k )
            invariant 0<=i<=j<=k<=input.Length;
/* the following invariants might not be maintained by the loop.*/
            invariant forall x:: 0<=x<i ==> input[x]==1;
            invariant forall x:: i<=x<j ==> input[x]==0;
            invariant forall x:: k<=x<input.Length ==> input[x]==2;
            invariant forall x:: j<=x<k ==> input[x]==0||input[x]==1||input[x]==2;
            decreases if j <= k then k - j else j - k
            {
                if(input[j] == 2){
                    swap(input, j, k-1);
                    k := k - 1;
                } else if(input[j] == 0){
                    j := j + 1;
                } else {
                    swap(input, i, j);
                    i:= i + 1;
                    j := j + 1;
                }
               }
            }
```

and here are `swap` method and `sorted` predicate

```
    predicate sorted(input:array?<int>)
    requires input!=null;
    requires input.Length>0;
    reads input;
    {
        forall i,j::0<=i<j<input.Length ==> input[i]==1 || input[i]==input[j] || input[j]==2
    }

    method swap(input: array?<int>, n:int, m:int)
    modifies input;
    requires input!=null;
    requires input.Length>0;
    requires 0<=n<input.Length && 0<=m<input.Length
    {
        var tmp : int := input[n];
        input[n] := input[m];
        input[m] := tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `swap` has no postcondition. The default postcondition is `true`, so the specification of `swap` says that it changes the array in any arbitrary way.

When the verifier sees a call to `swap` in the body of method `sort`, it only pays attention to `swap`'s specification --- not it's body. Thus, after the call to `swap`, the array could have any values in it at all, at least as far as the verifier can tell. So it is hardly surpising that any invariant relating to the contents of the array can not be proved.

The following specification for `swap` should work:

```
method swap(input: array?<int>, n:int, m:int)
    modifies input;
    requires input!=null;
    requires input.Length>0;
    requires 0<=n<input.Length && 0<=m<input.Length
    ensures n < m ==> input[..] == old( input[0..n] + [input[m]] + input[n+1..m] + [input[n]] + input[m+1..] ) ;
    ensures n==m ==> input[..] == old(input[..])
    ensures n > m ==> input[..] == old( input[0..m] + [input[n]] + input[m+1..n] + [input[m]] + input[n+1..] ) ;
```

So should this

```
method swap(input: array?<int>, n:int, m:int)
    modifies input;
    requires input!=null;
    requires input.Length>0;
    requires 0<=n<input.Length && 0<=m<input.Length
    ensures input[n] == old( input[m] ) ;
    ensures input[m] == old( input[n] ) ;
    ensures forall i | 0 <= i < input.Length && i != n && i != m :: input[i] == old(input[i])
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you, now much better understood how the tool works